# If Else in a While Loop

Tags: c

I am having trouble with this code.
When I run it, it only prints out two lines in the while statement.
I'm trying to get it to run the if statement until the MortgageLeft

Can someone see a mistake I'm making?
Idk if this helps, but if I delete the else statement, the program runs fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    float MortgageLeft, InterestRate, MonthlyPayment, MonIntRate, AmountOwed;
    int Month=0;

    printf("What is the value left on the mortgage?\n");
    scanf("%f", &MortgageLeft);

    printf("What is the annual interest rate of the loan, in percent?\n");
    scanf("%f", &InterestRate);

    printf("What is the monthly payment?\n");
    scanf("%f", &MonthlyPayment);

    MonIntRate= (InterestRate/12)/100;

    printf("Month\t\t Payment\t Amount Owed\n");

    while (MortgageLeft>0)
    {
        if(MortgageLeft>MonthlyPayment)
        {
            MortgageLeft=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
            MortgageLeft=MortgageLeft-MonthlyPayment;    
            Month++;
            printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\n", Month, MonthlyPayment, MortgageLeft);
        }
        else
            MortgageLeft=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
        Month++;
        printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t 0", Month, MortgageLeft);
        MortgageLeft=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are missing some brackets

```
while (MortgageLeft>0)
    {
        if(MortgageLeft>MonthlyPayment)
        {
        MortgageLeft=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
        MortgageLeft=MortgageLeft-MonthlyPayment;    
        Month++;
        printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\n", Month, MonthlyPayment, MortgageLeft);
        }
        else
        {
        MortgageLeft=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
        Month++;
        printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t 0", Month, MortgageLeft);
        MortgageLeft=0;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement you have this line `MortgageLeft=0;`. This is why your while loop keeps exiting. Also it appears that in your code you've posted you have neglected the curly braces around the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    float MortgageLeft, InterestRate, MonthlyPayment, MonIntRate, AmountOwed;
    int Month=0;

    printf("What is the value left on the mortgage?\n");
    scanf("%f", &MortgageLeft);

    printf("What is the annual interest rate of the loan, in percent?\n");
    scanf("%f", &InterestRate);

    printf("What is the monthly payment?\n");
    scanf("%f", &MonthlyPayment);

    MonIntRate= (InterestRate/12)/100;

    printf("Month\t\t Payment\t Amount Owed\n");

    while (MortgageLeft>0)
        {
            if(MortgageLeft>MonthlyPayment){
            MortgageLeft=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
            MortgageLeft=MortgageLeft-MonthlyPayment;    
            Month++;
            printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\n", Month, MonthlyPayment, MortgageLeft);
        }
            else
        {
            MortgageLeft=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
            Month++;
            printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t 0", Month, MortgageLeft);
            MortgageLeft=0;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sane formatting makes the problem apparent:

```
while (MortgageLeft > 0)
{
  if (MortgageLeft > MonthlyPayment)
  {
    MortgageLeft = (MortgageLeft * MonIntRate) + MortgageLeft;
    MortgageLeft = MortgageLeft - MonthlyPayment;    
    Month++;
    printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\n", Month, MonthlyPayment, MortgageLeft);
  }
  else 
    MortgageLeft = (MortgageLeft * MonIntRate) + MortgageLeft; // only this statement is 
                                                               // part of the else branch
  Month++;
  printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t 0", Month, MortgageLeft);
  MortgageLeft = 0;
}
```

You need braces around *all* the statements in the `else` branch:

```
while (MortgageLeft > 0)
{
  if (MortgageLeft > MonthlyPayment)
  {
    MortgageLeft = (MortgageLeft * MonIntRate) + MortgageLeft;
    MortgageLeft = MortgageLeft - MonthlyPayment;    
    Month++;
    printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f\n", Month, MonthlyPayment, MortgageLeft);
  }
  else 
  {
    MortgageLeft = (MortgageLeft * MonIntRate) + MortgageLeft; 
    Month++;
    printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t 0", Month, MortgageLeft);
    MortgageLeft=0;
  }
}
```

The compiler doesn't care about how you format your code, but it can make a *huge* difference in spotting errors (either by your or by a reviewer).  Whitespace is your friend; don't be afraid to put some breathing space between expressions and between lines of code.  Your eyes will thank you for it 25 years from now.  It really makes it easier for you and others to read, and it helps you to spot issues like this more easily.

IME, lining braces up directly with the beginning of the control structure makes those structures much easier to follow.  2 to 4 spaces of indentation is all you need to clearly display scope.

**EDIT**

As evidenced by the fact that someone else edited the original code to make it easier to read.